# Can/how do you add a circle of references without breaking RI?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm primarily interested in pgsql for this, but I was wondering if there is a way in any RDBMS to do an insert operation, *without* disabling and re-enabling any FOREIGN KEY or NOT NULL constraints, on two tables that refer to each other.  (You might think of this as a chicken that was somehow born from its own egg.)

For a practical example, if you had a multiple-choice quiz system, with tables "question" and "answer", where question.correct_answer refers to answer.id, and answer.question refers to question.id, is it possible to add a question and its answers simultaneously?

(For the record, I'm aware that you can do the disabling and re-enabling in a transaction block, and that another solution is to not have a correct_answer column but instead have answer.correct as a boolean and have a check constraint making sure there's exactly one correct answer per question.  But I'm not curious about alternative solutions here.)

Comment: Poor title for the question.  Try to make it appropriate to the actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Hopefully the new title is more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you answered your own question - you have to make a transaction block. In PostgreSQL this should work:

```
BEGIN;
  SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
INSERT INTO questions (questionid, answerid, question)
  VALUES (1, 100, 'How long are Abraham Lincoln\'s legs?');
INSERT INTO answers (answerid, questionid, answer)
  VALUES (100, 1, 'Long enough to reach the ground.');
COMMIT;
```

It has to be in a transaction block because if either INSERT statement failed the database would be in an invalid state (table constraints not met).

Comment: The one problem with SET CONSTRAINTS in PostgreSQL is that it only defers foreign key constraints. For instance, you can't defer a NOT NULL constraint with it. In practice though, foreign key constraints are the most common.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in the following way:

1. Define Questions.correct_answer as a
   nullable column.
2. Insert row into Questions, with correct_answer set to NULL.
3. Insert row(s) into Answers, referencing the row in Questions.
4. UPDATE Questions SET correct_answer
   = ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I meant that it had to be such that it left the NOT NULL constraints intact.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, then Neall's answer is better, deferring constraint enforcement until the end of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case of one question and one answer it is advisable to just put all attributes into one table.